# How to register nix package after building?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

I know that a nix package from repository can be installed via:

```
 nix-env -i package-name
```

After that command executable file is on the path and it everything fine.

On project page I spot that a nix package could be build from source:

```
 nix-build -A package-name
```

Building completes successfully and path to executable is printed on console,
but current nix environment doesn't see the new program.
Sure I can modify PATH manually, but I would like to use nix-build option or
addition nix-env run and don't bother with modifying configuration files manually.

Comment: `nix-env` will compile the package if needed. In addition, `nix-build` will only build from source if needed. Otherwise it will use the existing compiled package.

Comment: It's also possible to `nix-env -i ./result` or any other /nix/store path.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment of Vladimir you can do:

```
nix-env -i -f default.nix
```

to install the single package defined in `default.nix` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934306/how-can-i-nix-env-install-a-derivation-from-a-nix-expression-file) and if you actually define in `default.nix` a set of packages then it would be like:

```
nix-env -i -A package-name -f default.nix
```

Note that if you are using flake you can use

```
nix profile install .#package-name
```